# Minimum KL divergence distribution with constant shift

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

I have a little trouble calculating the optimal distribution $P$ with fixed variance value that minimizes the following KL divergence:
$$KL(x||x-\epsilon),$$
where $\epsilon$ is known and $x\sim P$. Not sure whether it would be related but if the objective is the entropy instead of the KL, the optimal solution would be Gaussian distribution by solving the Lagrangian function of the objective. I wonder whether there would be some similar solutions when the objective is KL divergence instead of the entropy?

Comment: The answer is not Gaussian. Consider two cases: P is Laplace with mean zero and variance one. P is Gaussian with mean zero and variance one. Using the result here you can compute the KL between two Laplace distributions:

https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2021/supplemental/Meyer_An_Alternative_Probabilistic_CVPR_2021_supplemental.pdf

I tried to plot the KL and it turns out that if $|\epsilon|<1.808$ then KL between to Gaussian is smaller otherwise KL between to Laplace.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah this makes sense to me and via Lagrangian form, I also know that Gaussian should not be the optimal solution but I just do not know how to solve the Lagrangian and obtain the final solution.